# two questions about Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

I am reading an article [Modular Arithmetic](http://www.ias.edu/about/publications/ias-letter/articles/2012-summer/modular-arithmetic-taylor) by Richard Taylor.    I have 2 questions:

1. For which $n$, $x^2+y^2=nz^2$ has nontravial solutions? What are the solutions?
2. A beautiful theorem of Hermann Minkowski and Helmut Hasse  says that if $Q (X_1 , ..., X_d ) $ is any homogeneous quadratic polynomial in any number of variables with whole number coefficients, then

$$Q (X_1 , ..., X_d ) $$

has a non-zero solution in whole numbers if and only if it has a non-zero solution in all (real) numbers and a primitive solution modulo $m$ for all positive whole numbers $m$

How to prove the beautiful theorem? Could you recommend some books?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) We have 
$$
\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^2=n,
$$
so the answer is given by Fermat’s two square theorem for rationals:

**Theorem (Fermat):** A positive rational number is a sum of two rational squares if and only if in its prime factorization every prime of the form $4k + 3$ appears with an even exponent.

For proofs see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88539/sums-of-rational-squares.

2.) See the references given here: [Proof of Hasse-Minkowski over Number Field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368756/proof-of-hasse-minkowski-over-number-field). I would say, "J.P. Serre: A course in arithmetic" is a good source.